# Run three Node scripts in three home directories in one command

Tags: node.js, unix, keystonejs

So I want to run three servers for three applications from one root script, as part of an Elastic Beanstalk deployment.  My setup looks like this:

```
/package.json
/directory1/keystone.js
/directory2/keystone.js
/directory3/keystone.js
```

In `package.json` I'm trying to write an `npm start` that'll kick all three of these off, but running `node directory1/keystone.js` kicks the server off in this root directory, not the `directory1` directory, which breaks all of the paths in the application.  So I need to actually `cd` into each directory before I run the server files.  My latest attempt was this:

`(cd directory1 && node keystone.js) & (cd directory2 && node keystone.js) & (cd directory3 && node keystone.js)`

But it only runs the first one.  The trick is that each of these servers occupies the shell with a request monitor, so I need to have them running in the background with no output so I can move on to the next command.  I tried a version with `cd ..` in between each call, but the monitor still seems to block any further commands.  How can I run sequential (or parallel) commands in a single shell without being blocked by shell-occupying things like request monitors?

Running this on Win10 for development, but will ultimately run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (cd directory1 && node keystone.js) & (cd directory2 && node
>   keystone.js) & (cd directory3 && node keystone.js)

This would only work for the first command because at that point, you are in the directory1. You will need to go back up a level and then cd into directory2. Also, if you need to run the node command in the background, add the '&' to the end. Something like this:

> (cd directory1 && node keystone.js &) & (cd ../directory2 && node
>   keystone.js &) & (cd ../directory3 && node keystone.js &)

You could also try chaining with the ';' character. Something like this:

> cd directory1; node keystone.js &; cd ../directory2; node keystone.js
>   &; cd ../directory3; node keystone.js &;